# Read a string input

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write instance of Read class to read an input as string as follow:

```
"1 3 -    
 - 2 3      
 - - 5"
```

Convert it into `[[Maybe Int]]`

"-" will be translated into `Nothing`
"3" will be `Just 3`

```
"('a',3) - ('b',7)
 ('c',5) ('e',0) -  
 ('d',9) - ('h',8)"
```

Convert it into `[[Maybe (Char,Int)]]`

"-" will be translated into Nothing
"('a',3)" will be `Just ('a',3)`

I tried to write them by handling with List of Char, but it takes a lot of work. Do you have any suggestion? Sorry, I am quite new to Haskell, so I ask you that question. :(

Comment: Actually, I want to convert it into [[Maybe Int]]. '-' will be translated into Nothing. '3' will be Maybe Char. But a string is quite general, unknown type in it, just only know parameters are seperated by a space or many spaces, and they are written in many lines (not one line)

Comment: This edit makes it much clearer, thanks.

Comment: You might be interested in the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553794/read-instance-causes-parse-error/13554910#13554910)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you got rid of the `-` entries, you could do this very quickly as

```
Prelude> (map (map read) . map words. lines $ "('a',3) ('b',4)\n('c',5)")::[[(Char,Int)]]
[[('a',3),('b',4)],[('c',5)]]
```

Or define it as a function

```
genericReadLines :: Read a => String -> [[a]]
genericReadLines = map (map read) . map words. lines
```

Which you can use thus:

```
*Main> (genericReadLines "('a',3) ('b',4)\n('c',5)")::[[(Char,Int)]]
[[('a',3),('b',4)],[('c',5)]]
```

but you may find it easier to do

```
readCharInts :: String -> [[(Char,Int)]]
readCharInts = genericReadLines

readInts :: String -> [[Int]]
readInts = genericReadLines
```

So you can just type

```
*Main> readInts "1 2 3\n4 5 6\n7 8 9"
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
*Main> readCharInts "('a',3) ('b',4)\n('c',5)"
[[('a',3),('b',4)],[('c',5)]]
```

---

But what about keeping the `-`? You'll have to use a Maybe data type, to represent not having a value for certain points in your list; we can use `-` as shorthand for `Nothing` and `a` as shorthand for `Just a`.

```
read' :: Read a => String -> Maybe a
read' "-" = Nothing
read' xs = Just (read xs)
```

I should warn you that that code is fragile if your data could possibly be `'-'`, but perhaps it can't.

```
genericMaybeReadLines :: Read a => String -> [[Maybe a]]
genericMaybeReadLines = map (map read') . map words. lines
```

Then we can have

```
readMaybeCharInts :: String -> [[Maybe (Char,Int)]]
readMaybeCharInts = genericMaybeReadLines

readMaybeInts :: String -> [[Maybe Int]]
readMaybeInts = genericMaybeReadLines
```

So now we can do

```
*Main> readMaybeCharInts "('a',3) ('b',4)\n- ('c',5)"
[[Just ('a',3),Just ('b',4)],[Nothing,Just ('c',5)]]
*Main> readMaybeInts "2 3 -\n4 - 2"
[[Just 2,Just 3,Nothing],[Just 4,Nothing,Just 2]]
```

Comment: I still have to deal with '-', and variables in a string can be separated by one or many spaces. Sorry for not clear enough

Comment: Wow, great. Thanks @AndewC so much. I got it. I was searching for some module like Pandoc, or Text.Parsec. But what a surprise that we can parse it without using external module of parser.

Comment: But it's quite weird that read method is not visible of Class Read. How can I apply these functions into read method of class Read?

Comment: Thank you, I know what to do. I wrote function readsPec like that:  readsPrec _ s = [(  readMaybeInts s , "")] and it works, even I guess the second parameter (that I assigned it to empty string "") is the result of transformation (from string to my data type)