# read instance causes parse error

Tags: haskell

I want to implement an instance of read that enables me to read a string (ex: "- - 8 - 3 -") and construct a list containing those values.

```
data Value a = Nul | Val a

showsValue :: (Show a) => Value a -> ShowS
showsValue (Val x) =  ("Value" ++) . shows x
showsValue (Nul)   =  ("Nothing 0" ++)

instance Show a => Show (Value a) where
    showsPrec _ x = showsValue x

instance Read a => Read (Value a) where
    readsPrec _ m = readsMatrix m

readsMatrix :: (Read a) => ReadS (Value a)
readsMatrix ('-':s) = [(Nul, rest) | (' ',rest) <- reads s]
readsMatrix s       = [(Val x,rest)| (x,' ':rest) <- reads s]
```

After performing this test:

```
read "- 8 - - 3" :: Value Int
```

I get the error `*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse`

What am I doing wrong here?

*update*

```
readsMatrix ('-':s) = [(Nul, dropWhile isSpace s)]
readsMatrix s = [(Val x, dropWhile isSpace rest) | (x,rest) <- reads s]
```

Comment: You might be interested in the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546779/read-a-string-input).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Correcting read for Value a

First, don't bother removing spaces, that's all handled fine by `reads`:

```
readsMatrix :: (Read a) => ReadS (Value a)
readsMatrix ('-':s) = [(Nul, dropWhile (==' ') s)]
readsMatrix s       = [(Val x,rest)| (x,rest) <- reads s]
```

Your read instance is now fine for single Values:

```
*Main> read "4" :: Value Int
Value4
*Main> read "-" :: Value Int
Nothing 0
```

### Correcting read for [Value a]

But you want to read lists as separated by spaces, so since that's non-standard behaviour, you'll need to write a custom `readList :: :: ReadS [Value a]`

```
instance Read a => Read (Value a) where
    readsPrec _ m = readsMatrix m
    readList s = [(map read.words $ s,"")]
```

So now

```
*Main> read "- 4 2 - 5" :: [Value Int]
[Nothing 0,Value4,Value2,Nothing 0,Value5]
```

but unfortunately,

```
*Main> read "- 4 2 \n- 5 4" :: [Value Int]
[Nothing 0,Value4,Value2,Nothing 0,Value5,Value4]
```

and even worse,

```
*Main> read "- 4 2 \n- 5 4" :: [[Value Int]]
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

### Reading a matrix

There's no straightforward way round this that I can see, because there's no `readListOfLists` in the `Read` class, so why not make a standalone function

```
matrix :: Read a => String -> [[Value a]]
matrix = map read.lines
```

so that

```
*Main> matrix "3 4 -\n3 - 6\n4 5 -" :: [[Value Int]]
[[Value3,Value4,Nothing 0],[Value3,Nothing 0,Value6],[Value4,Value5,Nothing 0]]
```

### Show isn't what I would choose

I think your `Show` instance for `Value` is a little misleading (`Nul` doesn't have a zero on it, `Val` isn't written `Value`). Either write

```
data Value a = Nul | Val a  deriving Show
```

so that it looks as it is or define it to match the `Read` instance

```
instance Show a => Show (Value a) where
  show Nul = "-"
  show (Val a) = show a
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `readsMatrix` function, you have

```
readsMatrix ('-':s) = [(Nul, rest) | (' ',rest) <- reads s]
```

That means after the `'-'` is consumed, the remainder of the input string is passed to

```
reads :: ReadS Char
```

but the `Read` instance for `Char` expects a character enclosed in single quotes, like `'h'`.

To get an element `(' ',rest)` in the result, you need - after optional whitespace before it - the character sequence `'\'' : ' ' : '\'' : whatever`. You don't have those in your expected input. What you want to do there is removing the space after the `'-'`, so if the space is optional, and may be more than one character long,

```
readsMatrix ('-':s) = [(Nul, dropWhile isSpace s)]
```

would work (if newlines, tabs etc. are also to be ignored). If you just want one mandatory space, the pattern should be

```
readsMatrix ('-':' ':s) = [(Nul, s)]
```

The second equation

```
readsMatrix s       = [(Val x,rest)| (x,' ':rest) <- reads s]
```

may work as is, but requires that values are followed by a space, so for example `readMatrix "3" :: [(Value Int, [Char])]` would return an empty list.

I think you'd rather have the space optional there too, so maybe

```
readsMatrix s = [(Val x, dropWhile isSpace rest) | (x,rest) <- reads s]
```

is what you want, but since `reads` ignores leading whitespace for most types,

```
readsMatrix s = [(Val x, rest) | (x, rest) <- reads s]
```

may be better.

But you're not ignoring leading whitespace before a `'-'`, so that would need to be done too.

Maybe the implementation would be better done using

```
lex :: ReadS String
```

from the `Prelude`, that splits a string into tokens roughly following the Haskell syntax, e.g.

```
ghci> lex "(12 + 34)  abc"
[("(","12 + 34)  abc")]
```

splits off the opening parenthesis, from the remainder the token `"12"` would be split off etc.

One possibility using `lex`, so that leading whitespace is duly ignored would be

```
readsMatrix s = do
        (tok, rest) <- lex s
        case tok of
           "-" -> return (Nul, rest)
           _   -> case reads tok of
                    [(x,"")] -> return (Val x, rest)
                    _ -> []
```

Finally,

```
read "- 8 - - 3" :: Value Int
```

would lead to a `*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse` even then, because `read` only succeeds if there is only whitespace following the converted token, but after converting the initial `'-'` there are still four more convertible tokens in the remainder of the input.

```
read "- 8 - - 3" :: [Value Int]
```

on the other hand should succeed.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent explanation. I tried what you suggested, but I have problems when I try to read a string with more then one element, because of the white spaces before the convertable tokens. I tried with the types [Value Int], but that didn't work either.

Comment: I've added a quick implementation using `lex` to ignore leading spaces. Another option would be `case dropWhile isSpace s of { '-':rest -> [(Nul, rest)]; other -> [(Val x, rest) | (x,rest) <- reads other] }`.